# Show that $Y\cup A$ or $Y\cup B$ are connected using the following criteria

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem.**
>
> Let $Y\subseteq X$ and let $X$ and $Y$ be connected. If $A$ and $B$ forms a separation of $X\setminus Y$, then show that $Y\cup A$ or $Y\cup B$ is connected by using the criteria of connectedness that if for any continuous function $f$ such that $f:X\to \{\pm1\}$, $f$ is constant then $X$ is connected.

I couldn't proceed significantly in this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This seems to be false. What if $X = \{y,a,b\}$ with the discrete topology, $Y = \{y\}$, $A = \{a\}$, and $B = \{b\}$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Sorry. In the question, there was a typo.

Comment: My counterexample still looks valid to me, even now that you have edited the question.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: It is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose towards a contradiction that both $Y \cup A$, $Y \cup B$ are disconnected.

Then what do you get from the definition?

Then, how can you use the connectedness of $Y$?

Comment: From the definition I get that there exist two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that both $f:Y\cup A\to \{\pm 1\}$ and $g:Y\cup B\to \{\pm 1\}$ are not constant. The only way to use the connected of $f$ that comes to my mind is to consider the restrictions $f\restriction_Y$ and  $g\restriction_Y$ and then from the connectedness of $Y$ I will be able to conclude that both these restrictions are constant. But I don't understand how does this help (if at all).